# Python pickling error trying to pickle pygame Event object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pickle

I am trying to pickle a pygame.event.Event object:

```
eventObj= pygame.event.get()[0]
data= pickle.dumps(eventObj)
```

but I get this error:

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'Event'>: attribute lookup builtins.Event failed
```

Comment: What `type(enventObj)` returns?

Comment: `type(eventObj)` returns `<class 'Event'>` as it should

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pygame.event.Event` can't be pickled.

You need to pickle `eventObj.type` and `eventObj.dict` separately, that's should be all you'll need from the event anyway.